# How to group multidimension array by key with php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 78
            [mount] => 78
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-01
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 130
            [mount] => 130
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-02
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-02
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 210
            [mount] => 210
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-03
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 190
            [mount] => 190
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-04
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-04
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 250
            [mount] => 250
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-05
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-05
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
            [mount] => 300
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-06
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-06
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 330
            [mount] => 330
            [1] => activation
            [type] => activation
            [2] => 2013-10-07
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-07
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [mount] => 100
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-01
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-01
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [mount] => 310
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-02
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-02
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
            [mount] => 200
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-03
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-03
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 400
            [mount] => 400
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-04
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-04
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 470
            [mount] => 470
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-05
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-05
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 310
            [mount] => 310
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-06
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-06
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 600
            [mount] => 600
            [1] => revenue
            [type] => revenue
            [2] => 2013-10-07
            [insertdate] => 2013-10-07
        )

)
```

The goal is to convert it to 1 dimension array which result as:

```
array([type]=>activation [mount]=>78,130,210,190,250,300,330),
array([type]=>revenue [mount]=>100,310,200,400,470,310,600)
```

Comment: Simple foreach will do the job...

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way to do it with PHP4 and newer, the function is called array_merge_recursive(). It will merge the sub arrays into a single one. If there are identical keys, this will be merged into a single key with an array as a value.

See the full documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the best variant, but anyway, it's works

```
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $array2[$value['type']][] = $value['mount'];
    }
    foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = array(
            'type' => $key,
            'mount' => implode(',', $value)
        );
    }
```